# What kind of occupation was a "piper"?

Tags: occupations

In an old parish record a John Colzear in 1598 is listed as a "piper". What kind of job is that?

Comment: Most likely a person who played the [pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uilleann_pipes). (musical instrument)

Comment: I must frequently remind myself that SE Code of Conduct is ["Be Nice"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240839/259135). I have deleted some comments to preserve that Code of Conduct.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

He was a musician who played the [pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_(instrument)). As in the phrase ['He who pays the piper calls the tune'](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/he-who-pays-the-piper-calls-the-tune).

Comment: In what circumstance could that be a paid occupation?

Comment: Pretty much anywhere that music was needed, e.g. street entertainment, wedding celebrations, military bands, etc.

Comment: interesting, never thought I'd find someone like that in my family tree in that time period!

Comment: In some cases it was a hereditary position - piper to a clan chief like the MacCrimmons, pipers to Clan Macleod for example. The name Colzear sounds Lowland Scots.

Comment: In this case, the "pipe" in question was almost certainly a bagpipe.